# Calling a Rest Service from another service for course registration system with spring boot

Tags: java, rest, api, spring-boot, microservices

I was trying to make a **REST** call(***Student, Course micro service)*** from my **Registration** micro service for *inserting* a new Registration but whenever i am calling those services **Student** micro service is showing the following **error**.

```
> org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [class com.homeexam.registrationmanagementserver.model.Student] and content type [application/json;charset=UTF-8]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.homeexam.registrationmanagementserver.model.Student` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.homeexam.registrationmanagementserver.model.Student` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
```

I tried my best to resolve the problem searching from google but i can't find any relevant solution regarding the problem. Help, me out!

This is My **RegistrationService** class where i am calling those micro services:

```java
    public Registration create(Registration registration) {

            Student student = restTemplate.getForObject(studentsUrl, Student.class);
            Section section = restTemplate.getForObject(sectionsUrl, Section.class);
            Course course = restTemplate.getForObject(coursesUrl, Course.class);


            /*registration = new Registration(registration.getId(), student.getId(),student.getProgram(),
                    section.getSectionNumber(),course.getCourseCode(),section.getFacultyInitial());*/
            registration.setId(registration.getId());
            registration.setStudentId(student.getId());
            registration.setProgramName(student.getProgram());
            registration.setCourseCode(course.getCourseCode());
            registration.setFacultyInitial(section.getFacultyInitial());
            registration.setSectionNumber(section.getSectionNumber());

            Optional<Registration> optionalReg = registrationRepository.findById(registration.getId());
            Optional<Registration> byCourseCode = registrationRepository.findById(Integer.valueOf(registration.getCourseCode()));
            if (optionalReg.isPresent() ) {
                throw new ResourceAlreadyExistsException();
            } else if (byCourseCode.isPresent())
               throw new AlreadyRegisteredException();
            else {
               return registrationRepository.save(registration);
            }
        }
```

But, code does work without calling the Micro service related info.

**Registration JSON**

```
{
  "courseCode": "string",
  "facultyInitial": "string",
  "id": 0,
  "programName": "string",
  "sectionNumber": 0,
  "studentId": "string"
}
```

**Student JSON**

```
{
    "id": "201600000001",
    "name": "UML Diagram",
    "email": "uml@gmail.com",
    "address": "Texas,USA",
    "dob": "1998-09-11",
    "mobileNumber": "01110000000",
    "dateOfAdmission": "2018-09-10",
    "program": "BSc. in EEE",
    "role": "Student",
    "password": "1555"
  }
```

**Course JSON**

```
[
  {
    "courseCode": "CS193",
    "courseTitle": "Android Application",
    "courseCredit": 3,
    "sectionList": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "sectionNumber": 1,
        "seatLimit": 25,
        "semesterNumber": 11,
        "facultyInitial": "ATA",
        "course": {
          "courseCode": "CS193",
          "courseTitle": "Android Application",
          "courseCredit": 3,
          "sectionList": null,
          "gradeList": null
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "sectionNumber": 2,
        "seatLimit": 30,
        "semesterNumber": 11,
        "facultyInitial": "ABA",
        "course": {
          "courseCode": "CS193",
          "courseTitle": "Android Application",
          "courseCredit": 3,
          "sectionList": null,
          "gradeList": null
        }
      }
    ],
    "gradeList": null
  }
]
```

**Section JSON**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "sectionNumber": 1,
    "seatLimit": 25,
    "semesterNumber": 11,
    "facultyInitial": "ATA",
    "course": {
      "courseCode": "CS193",
      "courseTitle": "Android Application",
      "courseCredit": 3,
      "sectionList": null,
      "gradeList": null
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "sectionNumber": 2,
    "seatLimit": 30,
    "semesterNumber": 11,
    "facultyInitial": "ABA",
    "course": {
      "courseCode": "CS193",
      "courseTitle": "Android Application",
      "courseCredit": 3,
      "sectionList": null,
      "gradeList": null
    }
  }
]
```

**Student.java**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id","name"})
@Document
public class Student {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String address;
    private LocalDate dob;
    private String mobileNumber;
    private LocalDate dateOfAdmission;
    private String program;
    private Role role;
    private String password;
}
```

**Registration.java**

```java
public class Registration {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String studentId;
    private String programName;
    private int sectionNumber;
    private String courseCode;
    private String facultyInitial;
}
```

Comment: The error message is related to a malformed JSON. Could you add the json content to the question?

Comment: @henriqueor i added the **JSON** data

Comment: could you please sahre Student.java

Comment: @deshi the following link contains the **Student.java** class 
[Student.java](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Wf2BhyjBmn/)

Comment: Always add the code to the question instead of on an external link, to keep history for future consults. @JakariaRidoy

Comment: @JakariaRidoy is the issue resolved?

Comment: @deshi No. But if i follow your suggestion i lost access to all the field of students.

Comment: Can you please share api contract detail of student, section and course

Comment: @deshi [Registration-System](https://github.com/ridoy19/Convocation-Registration-System) you can check my **Github** code here for Student and Course services.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that you send an array to the service that expects a single object.

Solution: Either send single JSON object per request or change the service so that it accepts array or list.

Comment: Which service layer should i change **StudentService** or **RegistrationService**

[StudentService.java](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/y72z9vKyBc/)

Comment: *whenever i am calling those services* - what does it have to do with other services? First analyze your service that is responsible for Student. Call GET from your preferred client (Postman, curlt, ...), check the structure. Call POST and PUT, check if they work correctly.

Comment: Both (Student and Course) service works fine. They can perform all CRUD operations.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably in the role property of Student. On your Student class, it expects to the receive a Role type, but in your JSON it's a String.

You have this:

```
{
    "id": "201600000001",
    "name": "UML Diagram",
    "email": "uml@gmail.com",
    "address": "Texas,USA",
    "dob": "1998-09-11",
    "mobileNumber": "01110000000",
    "dateOfAdmission": "2018-09-10",
    "program": "BSc. in EEE",
    "role": "Student",
    "password": "1555"
}
```

but should be something like this:

```
{
    "id": "201600000001",
    "name": "UML Diagram",
    "email": "uml@gmail.com",
    "address": "Texas,USA",
    "dob": "1998-09-11",
    "mobileNumber": "01110000000",
    "dateOfAdmission": "2018-09-10",
    "program": "BSc. in EEE",
    "role": {
        "type": "Student"
    },
    "password": "1555"
}
```

Since I don't know the Role class structure, I set the property "type" as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Student[] students = restTemplate.getForObject(studentsUrl, Student[].class);
```